# Cache for Web API

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api, outputcache

As all knows OutPutCache isn't work with Web API, so i try to search for another solution.
One is : [ASP.NET Web API CacheOutput](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/05/output-caching-in-asp-net-web-api/) but i don't know why this method didn't work for me. (Every time i get `Cache-Control:no-cache`. Method under is called from js script)

```
        [CacheOutput(ClientTimeSpan = 60, ServerTimeSpan = 60)]
        public virtual IEnumerable <UserDaysSummaryModel> Get(string startDate, string endDate)
        {
          ...
        }
```

Another solution : to use [Redis Cache Service on Azure](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis) but i didn't find any example how it work with Web API.

So what and how use caching for Web API and what method is the easiest for updating cache?

Comment: As an alternative, you can create a static MemoryCache class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @demo If you want to verify whether your caching is working, put a breakpoint in the body of your Get method above and run your webapp in debug mode. Hit the URL for it twice. The first time it should hit your breakpoint (remember to click continue after), the second time it should return results without hitting your breakpoint. The cache-control HTTP header isn't really all that useful for this type of caching.

Comment: @RaduPorumb, Hi. I can't debug the code, don't know why. Maybe because in project all requests go through angularJs (i am not friend with angular). But ASP.NET Web API CacheOutput don't work  in my case, also don't know why

Comment: You could put a caching layer between your data and the controller and forget about output caching altogether. Output caching was designed for web pages.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the below code to do caching in Web API

```
public class WebAPICachingHelper<T>
{
    public static ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
    public static T GetCacheValue(string key)
    {
        if(cache[key] != null)
        {
            return (T)cache[key];
        }
        return default(T);
    }

    public static void SetCacheValue<T>(string key, T t)
    {
        cache[key] = t;
    }
}
```